# Android NDK special character issue

Tags: android, string, android-ndk

I created a variable in C file like this:

char test1[50] = "Heloooo= \r\n how are you";

But, If I try to print this test1 variable not showing any output.

What is the issue?

Comment: What about another characters? Please, post more (relevant) code.

Comment: Values printed using __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

Comment: if use %s to print, not showing anything in output.

Comment: Issue only because of '\r' return character. Any idea? I tried to print ASCII value of this whole characters. But, its not showing any \r character ASCII value.